# Express.js use make additional route

Tags: node.js, express

I am using this line:

```
expressApp.use('/api/v1',require('./api')(expressApp));
```

To set up api version. But problem with this is it will give additional route:

`/api/v1/something` and `/api/v1//something`

Comment: what does it means `/api/v1/somthing and /api/v1//somthing` which one are you getting?

Comment: What does `./api.js` look like?

Comment: I get both thats problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can try  `expressApp.use('/',require('./api')(expressApp));`

I think this will be in the same root route.

Comment: I need just this `/api/v1/somthing`